A book a read about 20 years ago about children who communicate with "spirit writing."
From what I remember there is a group of children that communicate or gets clues from spirit writing. They jump from our world into another world and there are bad guys after them. I am sure there was a unicorn and parts of the book was wrote in maybe a tip or a desolate area.
I want to call it something like Elodor but that does not come up as a book in Google, so I know that the name is wrong.

I'm reasonable confident that you are describing "Elidor" by Alan Garner.  It is indeed about a group of children (Nicholas, David, Helen and Roland) who travel to another world to fulfil a quest.  They collect four treasures which they must protect, keep safe in our world.  Eventually they must return the treasures to the original world.  They come from a depressed British city (Manchester) - I always took it as describing ruins left after WWII.
Soldiers from the other world turn up to attack them, and search for the treasures which they have hidden.
There is an episode with a planchette in which they use it to receive a message from the other world.

"Is any one there?" she said to the ceiling, "Is anyone there?"
The planchette jerked as if Roland had cramp in his arm, and the pencil made a formless scribble on the wallpaper.

The message they get (shown as a freehand drawing, not text in the book) tells them that they must find a unicorn called Findhorn, but is very enigmatic.
The climax of the story is about a unicorn, called "Findhorn" if I recall correctly.  Only the girl can tame him.  They must get him to sing to save Elidor.  Eventually he sings and they return their treasures.
